# Mobile & Desktop CSS files, cookies and switching between the two

Tags: css, mobile, cookies, switch-statement, desktop

The web site I am currently working on is using a custom CMS, and there has been mobile integration using split CSS files, so I have:
- desktop.css
- mobile.css

There is a Javascript that detects screen size and serves the appropriate CSS file.

Users have the option to view the full site on a smaller screen, and view the smaller site on a larger screen, with cookies set in PHP as below:

```
$mob = '?setmob';
$mob_len = strlen($mob);
$self_end = substr($self, strlen($self) - $mob_len);
if($self_end == $mob){
$settomobile = 1;
}
else{

$full = '?setfull';
$full_len = strlen($full);
$full_end = substr($self, strlen($self) - $full_len);
if($full_end == $full){
$settofull = 1;
}
}

if($settomobile == 1)
{
    setcookie("viewing", "", time()-3600);
    setcookie("viewing", "mobile", time()+63113851);
}

if($settofull == 1)
{
    setcookie("viewing", "", time()-3600);
    setcookie("viewing", "desktop", time()+63113851);
}
```

The Javascript that detects the screen size and serves the CSS is:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function adjustStyle(width) {
width = parseInt(width);
if (width < 750) {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/mobile.css\");";
$mob = "Yes";
$top_contents .= "} else {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/$css_name.css\");  

}

}

function setToMobile() {
var width = 200;
if (width < 750) {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/mobile.css\");";
$mob = "Yes";
$top_contents .= "} else {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/$css_name.css\"); 
}
}

function setToDesktop() {
var width = 1000;
if (width < 750) {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/mobile.css\");";
$mob = "Yes";
$top_contents .= "} else {
$(\"#size-stylesheet\").attr(\"href\", \"/$css_name.css\"); 

}
}

$(function() {";
if(isset($_COOKIE['viewing']) || $settofull || $settomobile){
$view = $_COOKIE['viewing'];
if(($view == 'mobile' || $settomobile == 1) && !$settofull){
$top_contents .= "setToMobile();";
}
elseif(($view == 'desktop' || $settofull == 1) && !$settomobile){
$top_contents .= "setToDesktop();";
}
}
else{

$top_contents .= "   adjustStyle(screen.width);
";}
$top_contents .="
});         </script>";
}

$top_contents = $top_contents . "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/admin/css/$css_name.css\" id=\"size-stylesheet\" title=\"default\" />
```

The problem I am finding is that the web site has to launch the normal CSS first, before the Javascript kicks in to redirect users to the mobile CSS.

Is there a simple way I can fix this so users don't have to see the full site before the mobile CSS loads?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: you can use mobile query .

Comment: What do you mean by mobile query?

Comment: should be **media query** . see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for typo in comments, should be media queries. For example:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

See more examples in Reference link below.

Reference: [Media Queries in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: I tried using media queries, but they stop users from being able to select their own viewing choice, which is the problem - I know there are mobile users who are happy to view the full site and zoom and pan around, and I know there are tablet users who would prefer to use the simple mobile version on 3G, rather than use the full site (which is tablet-friendly)!

I can't find a way to use the media query and allow users to click between, which is why the Javascript is used, with the cookie to remember settings.

Is there any other way to get round the issue of the desktop.css loading first?

Comment: Try this: http://yepnopejs.com/ . This conditionally loads what you want, along with media queries & JS .